# Bounds on Fourier coefficients by total variation

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series, bounded-variation

The following is a question from the book *Fourier and Wavelet Analysis*
by George Bachmann, Lawrence Narici, Edward Beckenstein (Section 4.3, Question no. 8).

**Question: The Fourier sine and cosine coefficients $c_n$ of $f\in BV[-\pi,\pi]\subset L^1_\Bbb R[-\pi,\pi]$ satisfy $$|c_n|\le \frac{1}{n\pi}V(f,[-\pi,\pi])$$**

**and these estimates cannot be improved.**

But when I consider the following function $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to \Bbb R$ by 
$$f(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{1 1}
  0  & \mbox{if } & -\pi\le x <0 \\
  1 & \mbox{if } & 0\le x\le\pi
 \end{array}
\right.$$

Then the Fourier cosine coefficients $a_0=1, a_n=0$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}(1-(-1)^n)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Also $f$ is of bounded variation with total variation $V(f,[-\pi,\pi])=1$. Thus $f$ satisfies the above requirement of the question.

But for $n$ odd, $|b_n|=\frac{2}{n\pi}$. Thus we obtain that $|b_n|>\frac{1}{n\pi}V(f,[-\pi,\pi])$ for odd values of $n$.

Now my question is that **is the above estimate in the question correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin((2n+1)x)dx  & =\frac{1}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin
t\,dt=\frac{1}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin t\,dt\\
& =\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\sin t\,dt+\frac
{1}{2n+1}\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin t\,dt\\
& =\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin t\,dt+\frac{1}{2n+1}%
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin t\,dt\\
& =0+\frac{2}{2n+1},
\end{align*}
so $b_{2n+1}=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$. I went to check the original paper [Izumi](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195521140) and there are two mistakes. One is that $2\pi|a_n|$ should be $\pi |a_n|$ and the other is that they forgot the absolute value in $|\cos nx|$. So you get
$$
\int_{-\pi/(2n)}^{\pi/(2n)}|\cos nx|dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi
/2}\left\vert \cos t\right\vert \,dt=\frac{2}{n}%
$$
where $t=nx$ so $dt=ndx$. So they actually prove that $|a_n|\le 2V/\pi n$.